# Need Basic CURL POST Request & HTTP Header Assistance

Tags: http, curl, header, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I've tried this every which way, but, I cannot seem to get the syntax right (though I can make it work through a website such as hurl.it). I'm trying a basic HTTP POST request with CURL and I need it to do the following:

1.) Be able to do a very basic non-oauth login (username and password) to http://www.fake.site/create
2.) Send over a few HTTP headers such as "Host, Connection, Content-Length, User-Agent, etc."
3.) Be able to pass over 1 parameter in this format {"guid":"","style":"The Style Here"}
4.) Be able to follow a redirect(s)

I would appreciate any assistance you may have--I have literally been to over 5 pages of Google results and I just hit a snag at ever turn with my CURL code.

Help and Thank you!

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: The most recent was: curl --user name:password http://www.example.com -H "Host:example.com" -H "Content-Length:123456" --data "guid=value1&style=value2" http://www.example.com

Comment: mississippi-joe You haven't posted anything on your comment.

Comment: If I fill out the form on hurl.it, it works flawlessly. I just need the terminal equivalent of whatever hurl.it sends to the serve in the obvious terminal language.

Comment: (shameless promo!!) when debugging issues like this, we have great tools for capturing what your curl command is sending: https://www.runscope.com/#debugging

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -X POST -L
  -u "auth-User:auth-password"
  -d "{\"guid\":\"\",\"style\":\"The Style Here\"}"
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  "http://www.fake.site/create"
```

You can add more headers through `-H` parameter if you want.